# RequireJS `!` Syntax - What is it?

Tags: javascript, angular, requirejs

I am pretty new to JS. Here's `define` section of our application:

```
define([
   'angular',
   'underscore',
   'text!./ItemsList.html',
   'less!./ItemsList',
   ]
```

What's the point of `text!.` and `less!.`? Is that some kind of pre-processing?

Comment: I'd assume it's a webpack/require filter for a plugin. --- Also, if it's your application, why don't you know this already?

Comment: It's just text, isn't it? It depends on the code that consumes the data. Angular?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Angular, yes.

Comment: I think you could figure out on the documentation: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `require.js` module definition. This `text!` and `less!` are definitions of the module in charge of import the file. There're many modules, like `json!` to load specific type of files (custom module load `.js`files usually)

Take a look at the requirejs text [documentation](https://github.com/requirejs/text)